# How to compile libgit2 without HTTPS

Tags: libgit2

I'm trying to compile a no or limited libgit2 static build but haven't yet succeeded into compiling it without openssl.

So far, my best attempt has been following this suite of commands:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DCMAKE_DISABLE_FIND_PACKAGE_OpenSSL=TRUE
make
```

But I obtain the following:

```
[ 11%] Building C object CMakeFiles/git2.dir/src/openssl_stream.c.o
/Users/raphael/src/github.com/libgit2/libgit2/src/openssl_stream.c:369:41: warning: unused parameter 'out' [-Wunused-parameter]
int git_openssl_stream_new(git_stream **out, const char *host, const char *port)
                                        ^
/Users/raphael/src/github.com/libgit2/libgit2/src/openssl_stream.c:369:58: warning: unused parameter 'host' [-Wunused-parameter]
int git_openssl_stream_new(git_stream **out, const char *host, const char *port)
                                                         ^
/Users/raphael/src/github.com/libgit2/libgit2/src/openssl_stream.c:369:76: warning: unused parameter 'port' [-Wunused-parameter]
int git_openssl_stream_new(git_stream **out, const char *host, const char *port)
```

Then:

```
[ 23%] Building C object CMakeFiles/git2.dir/src/hash/hash_generic.c.o
In file included from /Users/raphael/src/github.com/libgit2/libgit2/src/hash/hash_generic.c:10:
/Users/raphael/src/github.com/libgit2/libgit2/src/hash/hash_generic.h:13:8: error: redefinition of 'git_hash_ctx'
struct git_hash_ctx {
       ^
/Users/raphael/src/github.com/libgit2/libgit2/src/hash/hash_common_crypto.h:15:8: note: previous definition is here
struct git_hash_ctx {
       ^
```

And many others obviously following.

Environment details:

I'm on MacOS X Yosemite, using either Clang or GCC 4.9 and I'm building statically, I tried with tag v0.22.1 and master from Jan 24, 2015.

I'm looking for a process that would be portable to Linux / FreeBSD as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warnings about the openssl stream are irrelevant; the constructor simply returns an error, so it doesn't use any of the parameters passed. It'd be nice to clean the up, but they don't do anything.

As for the redefinition issue, you can find a workaround in [PR 2820](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/2820).

Comment: Works well, and the workaround shouldn't necessary on Linux or FreeBSD, thanks !